# Change Right-click menu background color

Tags: 12.04, menu, colors, gtk3, ambiance

I'm using a modified Ambience theme (found in the Ambience-colors package, here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/download-ambiance-and-radiance-themes.html ) and the right-click menus of the Ambiance colored themes are white, just like the original Ambiance theme on 12.04 (but there are mods for that one)

How can I change the color of the right-click menu to black with the Ambiance-*color* theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [How To :Revert to Dark Menus for Ambiance Theme in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-revert-to-dark-menus-for-ambiance-theme-in-ubuntu-12-04)